# Mongocxx in Windows LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_mongoc_read_prefs_new

Tags: c++, mongodb, mongo-c-driver, mongo-cxx-driver

I have followed the instructions in the following document to the letter (including the instructions for building mongo-c-driver): https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-cxx-driver/mongocxx-v3/installation/

I am attempting to build the sample code provided (using VS2015), which I shall copy paste for convenience:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <bsoncxx/builder/stream/document.hpp>
#include <bsoncxx/json.hpp>

#include <mongocxx/client.hpp>
#include <mongocxx/instance.hpp>

int main(int, char**) {
    mongocxx::instance inst{};
    mongocxx::client conn{ mongocxx::uri{} };

    bsoncxx::builder::stream::document document{};

    auto collection = conn["testdb"]["testcollection"];
    document << "hello" << "world";

    collection.insert_one(document.view());
    auto cursor = collection.find({});

    for (auto&& doc : cursor) {
        std::cout << bsoncxx::to_json(doc) << std::endl;
    }
}
```

I have specified the header and library include directories according to the project settings provided. I have also added the MONGOCXX_STATIC and BSONCXX_STATIC preprocessor definitions.

Initially I added the following libs to the linker settings: `libmongocxx.lib;libbsoncxx.lib;mongoc-static-1.0.lib;bson-1.0.lib;`

When compilation failed I tried using the static bson lib (not sure why the documentation suggests using the non-static one?), so my input libs are now as follows: `libmongocxx.lib;libbsoncxx.lib;mongoc-static-1.0.lib;bson-static-1.0.lib;`

Despite my best efforts, and frantic googling, I get around 2000 unresolved externals, an example of which I've copied and pasted below:

```
libmongocxx.lib(distinct.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_mongoc_read_prefs_new
```

It appears as though it is coming from mongo c driver. I have seen [this SO article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41568548/libmongocxx-lib-error-lnk2001-unresolved-external-symbol), but I am already linking mongoc-static-1.0.lib as stated above - unfortunately there is little else to go on in this post. The compiler is clearly finding said lib (otherwise it would complain with "not found" errors), so I can only think that I have somehow built the lib incorrectly.

I'll also mention at this point that I have successfully built and run the code using the non-static libs and dlls - however, it is highly desirable to avoid having to use dlls and so I would like to use the static libs if possible.

I have read the installation instructions several times now, and something that sticks out at me is the following:

> If you need static libraries, be sure to use the --enable-static configure option when building libmongoc.

However, this appears to be appropriate only for installing in Linux, I am installing in Windows using CMake. I ran CMake.exe -LH to see what available options there were in the hope of finding something about static libs, but no dice. It appears that there are no options necessary for building the static libs, since when I installed mongo-c-driver, I successfully obtained the bson-static-1.0.lib and mongoc-static-1.0 libs.

I find myself at a loss! Any help would be greatly appreciated, cheers.

Comment: Note: this was also posted to the mongodb-user mailing list and is being discussed there: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongodb-user/iUaqAMScXMM

Answer (score 1):

Have you resolved the problems? I have similar problems. However, it seems fine if you use older drivers, like mongoc 1.4, bson 1.4 and mongocxx 3.0, though they can only support mongodb 3.2 and older